# How can I use Gradle to configure different environments using a shared source set(main)?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to use Gradle Source Sets to configure different files for different environments, which is inspired by [Gradles integration testing setup documentation.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests)

My goal is to have both `fake` and `prod` source sets use interfaces defined in `main` and provide their own implementations. This is similar if not exactly what you can accomplish with the Android Gradle Plugin's [Product Flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors).

For example, here is my build.gradle.kts file:

```
...

sourceSets {
    create("prod") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output

        java.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin", "src/prod/kotlin")
    }

    create("fake") {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.get().output

        java.srcDirs("src/main/kotlin", "src/fake/kotlin")
    }
}

val fakeImplementation by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

val prodImplementation by configurations.getting {
    extendsFrom(configurations.implementation.get())
}

configurations["fakeRuntimeOnly"].extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())
configurations["prodRuntimeOnly"].extendsFrom(configurations.runtimeOnly.get())

val prodTest = task<Test>("prodTest") {
    description = "Runs prod tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["prod"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["prod"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

val fakeTest = task<Test>("fakeTest") {
    description = "Runs fake tests."
    group = "verification"

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets["fake"].output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets["fake"].runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter("test")
}

tasks.check { dependsOn(prodTest) }
tasks.check { dependsOn(fakeTest) }

...
```

`compileFakeKotlin` doesn't recognize files in the `fake` source set, particularly on the `kaptKotlin` task which is defined like so in my `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {

    // Dagger
    implementation("com.google.dagger:dagger:2.41")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.41")
    "kaptProd"("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.41")
    "kaptFake"("com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.41")

}
```

And here is the error:

```
> Task :server:compileKotlinCheckIncrementalCompilationAnvil UP-TO-DATE
> Task :server:kaptGenerateStubsKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :server:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :server:compileFakeKotlinCheckIncrementalCompilationAnvil UP-TO-DATE

> Task :server:kaptKotlin FAILED
...[Dagger/MissingBinding] my.package.name.RecipeController cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface AppComponent { ...
```

When I put the binding class(FakeRecipeController.kt) in the main source set, it works perfectly. But when it's in src/fake/kotlin, I get this error which leads me to believe the code in that source set isn't being used and I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Thank you.

Comment: I’m not sure I see the point. Why not create a module for the interfaces, a module for each of prod and stub and then either switch the dependency out or even decide programmatically in the test. If you’re using a DI framework you could use something like Spring’s profiles.

Comment: I am using a DI framework, Dagger 2 in this case. I don't want to create separate modules because I believe it is bazooka to kill a fly in my use case(but not every use case, I still love using modules when I find it appropriate).